# How to get the file id of any file using its shared link?

Tags: file

I am in need of the file id of file stored in my box.net account from its shared link of that file. I have the shared link of my file, but there is no file id in that url. I need the file id of it.

Comment: Could you give an example of the shared link? It doesn't have to be a working one, just something to exemplify the format.

Comment: probably, a `https://www.box.com/s/4cqddrd62rs9ivy7wkdo` might be an example, a least judging from screenshots at [their support](https://support.box.com/entries/20353457-How-do-I-share-a-file-with-other-people-)

Answer (score 1):

Think I found what you need: http://developers.box.com/docs/#shared-items. See the example on the far right.

You need to send a request to https://api.box.com/2.0/shared_items. It needs to have two headers:

- `Authorization`: This header should contain `Bearer ACCESS_CODE`
- `BoxApi`: This head should contain `shared_link=SHARED_LINK`

The cURL example they give is

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/shared_items -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_CODE" -H "BoxApi: shared_link=SHARED_LINK"
```

According to the docs, that should return a JSON response that begins like the following:

```
{
    "type": "folder",
    "id": "11446498",
    "sequence_id": "1",
    "etag": "1",
    "name": "Pictures",
```

I believe `id` is the file's ID.